# How to find average of a column and average of subtraction of two columns in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am new to scripting using Pig Latin. I am stuck to write a pig script which will find the average of a column value and also to find the average of the subtracted values between two columns.

I am reading the data from a csv file having starttime and endtime columns as below:

```
"starttime","endtime",
"23","46",
"32","49",
"54","59"
```

The code that I have tried so far is as below :

```
file = LOAD '/project/timestamp.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (st:int, et:int);
start_ts = FOREACH file GENERATE st;
grouped = group start_ts by st
ILLUSTRATE grouped
```

The ILLUSTRATE output I am getting is as below and I am not able to apply the AVG function.

```
------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| grouped     | group:int     | file:bag{:tuple(st:int,et:int)}                 | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|             |               | {(, ), (, )}                                        | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anybody please help me getting the average of the starttime which would be the result of (23 + 32 + 54)/3

And also some ideas on how to code the (endtime -starttime)/no. of records (i.e 3 in this case) would be of great help for me to get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that you are loading the data correctly.Looks like you have double quotes i.e " around your data.Load the data as chararray,replace the double quotes and then cast it to int,finally apply the AVG function for the starttime.For the avg of endtime - starttime just subtract the 2 fields and apply AVG.

```
A = LOAD '/project/timestamp.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (st:chararray, et:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (int)REPLACE(st,'\\"','') as st,(int)REPLACE(et,'\\"','') as et;
C = GROUP B ALL;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE AVG(B.st),AVG(B.et - B.st);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the code that you posted, it already takes care of the double quotes by replacing them with ' '. So if I just LOAD the data set I provided which has double quotes around, will still work. However, I am getting below error after the second statement having REPLACE. : grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE (int)REPLACE(st, '\"', '') as st,(int)REPLACE(et,'\"', '') as et;
<line 2, column 42>  Unexpected character '"' . Please correct me if I am doing any mistake.

Comment: @H.Burns I've edited the line.Use \\ to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have managed to do it without the escape character. Also I needed to tweak the group by statement a bit. I have added my code only for the average of one column in the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @H.Burns Cool,glad it was helpful.kudos on getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file = LOAD '/project/timestamp.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (st:int, et:int);
grouped = group file by 1
AVG = foreach grouped generate AVG(file.st)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to inquisitive_mind. 
My answer is majorly based on his answer with a little tweak. 
This is only for the average of one column.

```
 file = LOAD '/project/timestamp.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (st:chararray, et:chararray);
cols  = FOREACH file GENERATE (int)REPLACE(st, '"', '') as st, (int)REPLACE(et, '"', '') as et;

grp_cols = GROUP cols all;


 avg = FOREACH grp_cols GENERATE AVG(cols.st);

DUMP avg
```